# Do triggers in salesforce have test class created by salesforce not by the developer?

Tags: trigger, failing-tests, migration-tool

I am using Ant Migration tool to deploy or retrieve my metadata in salesforce. I have a LeadTrigger that I fetch but when I was running the test before I deploy, I got the error that I didn't reach the code coverage. Now, the question is.. I don't have test class for Lead trigger that I created in my salesforce so where is this coming from?

[image]

build.xml

```
 <target name="deployMe">
          <sf:deploy username="${sf.username2}" password="${sf.password2}" serverurl="${sf.serverurl}" maxPoll="${sf.maxPoll}" deployRoot="fetcheddata" rollbackOnError="true" checkOnly="true" testLevel="RunLocalTests" />
   </target>
```

Comment: Screenshot is blur can you post the message in text format?

Comment: Code Coverage Failure:
Your organization's code coverage is 74%. You need at least 75% coverage to complete this deployment. Also, the following triggers have 0% code coverage. Each trigger must have at least 1% code coverage.
LeadTrigger

Comment: I think I see it now.. I have no test class for this LeadTrigger. Could it be the problem?

Comment: If you are deploying LeadTrigger test class is must

Comment: I got it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two options for test class while deploying to prod.

1. **RunLocalTests**: With this approach you will need to have org coverage minimum 75 during validation. Also for all triggers at least 1% code coverage is required. You have to write test class for lead trigger.
2. **RunSpecifiedTests**: With this approach you don't have to worry about org coverage. For classes/triggers you are deploying each file should have at least 75% coverage. If you are not deploying LeadTrigger then you won't have to write test class for it.

You can specify test class for covering class/trigger in following manner.

```
<target name="deployCode">
    <sf:deploy username="${sf.username}" password="${sf.password}" 
           sessionId="${sf.sessionId}" serverurl="${sf.serverurl}"
           deployroot="codepkg" testLevel="RunSpecifiedTests">
        <runTest>TestClass1</runTest>
        <runTest>TestClass2</runTest>
        <runTest>TestClass3</runTest>
    </sf:deploy>
</target>
```

Refer Salesforce [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.daas.meta/daas/forcemigrationtool_deploy_run_specific_tests.htm) for more info.